# How to count the repetition of duplicate elements that are in arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, collections

I was able to count the repetition elements but not in an efficient way. Basically i have an array list that is of type String. Example:

```
ArrayList<String> s=new ArrayList<String>();
```

if i print s using foreach then output is:

```
[1,2]
[1,4]
[4]
[3,5]
```

What is an efficient way to count repetition of numbers when there are multiple arrays? Any kind of help is appreciated.

Final Output:
1 is 2 times repeated.
2 is 1 time repeated.
so on

Comment: Please ask a clear question. Show your code. Provide example input + expected output.

Comment: extract the number from the `String` and use a `Map` to count the occurence for each of this numbers.

Comment: if the range of these numbers are small, you can even use an array whose index is the number and data is the count of this number. Otherwise, you can use a HashMap

Answer (score 2):

If you are open to using a third party library, you could use [GS Collections](https://github.com/goldmansachs/gs-collections) which has support for primitive bags.  Bag is a data structure that keeps track of the occurrences of each unique element.  Using an [IntBag](http://www.goldmansachs.com/gs-collections/javadoc/7.0.0/com/gs/collections/api/bag/primitive/IntBag.html) can reduce the amount of boxing you would otherwise need for your use case.

```
CharAdapter remove = CharAdapter.adapt("[]");
IntBag counts =
    Lists.mutable.with("[1,2]", "[1,4]", "[4]", "[3,5]")
        .asLazy()
        .collectWith(StringIterate::rejectChar, remove::contains)
        .flatCollect(StringIterate::csvTokensToList)
        .collectInt(Integer::parseInt)
        .toBag();
Assert.assertEquals(2, counts.occurrencesOf(1));
Assert.assertEquals(1, counts.occurrencesOf(2));
```

If you need the output sorted by value, you can use a `SortedBag<Integer>` instead.  Note however, this will result in boxing the ints to Integers.

```
CharAdapter remove = CharAdapter.adapt("[]");
SortedBag<Integer> counts =
    Lists.mutable.with("[1,2]", "[1,4]", "[4]", "[3,5]")
        .asLazy()
        .collectWith(StringIterate::rejectChar, remove::contains)
        .flatCollect(StringIterate::csvTokensToList)
        .collect(Integer::parseInt)
        .toSortedBag();
Assert.assertEquals(2, counts.occurrencesOf(1));
Assert.assertEquals(1, counts.occurrencesOf(2));
System.out.println(counts.toStringOfItemToCount());
```

Outputs:

```
{1=2, 2=1, 3=1, 4=2, 5=1}
```

**Note:** I am a developer on GS Collections

Answer (score 1):

You could use [a `counting` collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#counting--):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  List<String> s = Arrays.asList("[1,2]", "[1,4]", "[4]", "[3,5]");
  Map<Integer, Long> occurences = s.stream()
                  .flatMap(abc::parseString)
                  .collect(groupingBy(i -> i, counting()));
  System.out.println("occurences = " + occurences);
}

private static Stream<Integer> parseString(String s) {
  String[] numbers = s.substring(1, s.length() - 1).split(",");
  return Arrays.stream(numbers).map(Integer::parseInt);
}
```

output:

> occurences = {1=2, 2=1, 3=1, 4=2, 5=1}